# Console text appears on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I updated to 10.10 from 10.04 -however not with a clean install but with online update. Since then at shutdown some console texts appear (next to the red spot representing the shutdown steps). Im using the nvidia driver from nvidia.com.
Can you suggest something?

Comment: And what about your startup sequence? Is it normal ubuntu logo?

Comment: Happens for me to but does not affect the running of the computer so I really do not care. Terrible I know but just fine with me.

Answer (score 6):

This is not normal and looks like to be related to an issue with the proprietary Nvidia/ATI drivers.

See the bug reports on Launchpad [#563878](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/563878) and [#653274](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/653274).

Normally, during boot and shutdown Ubuntu is supposed to display a high-res Ubuntu logo and not show any text at all.

However, with Lucid Lynx and the recent Maverick Meerkat something changed that this does not work anymore for certain configurations.

For me, using the free open source driver this works as expected. However, using the proprietary AMD fglrx driver, both, the boot screen and the shutdown screen are replaced by ugly, low-res text.

This does not impact any functionality, but is just a cosmetic thing, which is hopefully attended to and fixed soon.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like I have found a solution for this problem **when using the ATI driver fglrx**.

Install the package`startupmanager` with `apt-get install startupmanager`.

Run it with `gksudo startupmanager` or by selecting `System->Administration->StartUp-Manager`.

On the `Boot Options` tab select the desired (high) resolution and color depth (24 bits). Check the box `Show Boot Splash`, uncheck the box `Show text during boot`.

Then hit `Close` and reboot. Now you should see the boot splash screen instead of the text during boot up and shut down.

This solved the problem for me.

**NOTE:** This might **not** solve the problem for people using the Nvidia graphics driver.

Answer (score 3):

i've also noticed that when using the proprietary graphics drivers on my system, it seems to interfere with the boot/shutdown splash page. it's not really a functionality problem, but if it bothers you you could file a bug or remove the nvidia driver (my system works quite well without it, as good support is provided by the kernel).

Comment: Bug reports have already been filed for this. See my answer for details.

Comment: thanks for the info cschol. i figured it was a known-issue, but it never bothered me, and i don't game w/ my system so prefer to avoid the whole proprietary-video cluster. no tainted kernel for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your referring to but log information displayed on shut down is perfectly normal. Usually when I shut down my laptop, I have a flash of console info like:

Checking Battery State..

Checking Unattended-upgrades

Before the Plymouth screen.

Normal behavior, so I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure thats normal...

Does it say anything particularly interesting?  Or is it just standard Debian halting garbage?

Comment: It would have been better to say this in a comment to the original question instead of an answer.

Comment: What can I say, I am still new to this whole "QA" system...

Comment: Actually it does not say any interesting just checking things before halting. Halt goes normal. However it looks a bit ugly - as Piedro said its not a good marketing for an otherwise very good system :) And i did not have this with 10.04.