# Stop Ubuntu from displaying Text before Shutting Down

Tags: shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Console text appears on logoff](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6101/console-text-appears-on-logoff)

As soon as i press the shutdown button in ubuntu 11.10 it displays text for a few seconds before actually shutting down, its annoying, is there a way to stop it?

Comment: This is a problem since lucid and still applies in oneiric.  I have read this may be resolved in 12.04 - still early days to confirm this.

Comment: Is that of any use to learn about ubuntu?