# How to not have console messages on shutdown?

Tags: boot, shutdown, plymouth

I got to eliminate almost every sign of a console from bootup to lightdm (only the quick appearance of a cursor from grub still annoys me) but shutdown is a mess: at least an "fsck clean" message appears, but sometimes more, right before plymouth kicks in.

I'd like it if:

- I could make the messages not appear, either by suppressing them
  (more difficult, since the fsck message is there from before
  lightdm... I can make it go away THEN but not on shutdown) or by
  making the font black on the console, which I don't know how to do on
  shutdown; or
- Plymouth kicked in earlier.

I tried this solution: [How to hide console messages on shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39110/how-to-hide-console-messages-on-shutdown) - but this is very old and we don't have an rc.conf anymore.

In this case: [Console text appears on shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6101/console-text-appears-on-shutdown) - there is a problem with nvidia but I have an integrated Intel, so it has nothing to do with that. Also people do not seem to care about the text - I KNOW it doesn't mean trouble, I just want to get rid of it.

In this case: [Console shows on shutdown/logout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271901/console-shows-on-shutdown-logout) - Comments to the answer just reassure it's normal behaviour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Ubuntu 18.04 Server LTS`, edit

`/etc/sysctl.d/10-console-messages.conf` and set

`kernel.printk = 0 4 1 7`

Actually the first value (0) is what you need. According to https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing, setting that first number to 0 means only "Emergency messages" are shown ("system is about to crash or is unstable").

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot I had asked this; meanwhile I replaced grub with booting with efi and it apparently solved the problem - but since this seems to be the way to go I'll mark it as the correct answer.